# xsd.exe just emits a single Object field when generating code from XSD

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xsd, xsd.exe

I have an XSD defined as follows (I anonymised the type names), you always get back a single `<response>` element:

```
<xsd:element name="response">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Root element of the all response XML's
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:choice>
                 <xsd:element name="TypeA" type="TypeAType" />
                 <xsd:element name="TypeB" type="TypeBType" />
                 <xsd:element name="TypeC" type="TypeCType" />
            </xsd:choice>

            <xsd:element name="error" type="xsd:string">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>
                        In case of error this will contain detailed error information
                        and no other sibling elements will exist.
                        If the request is successful this element will not exist.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

When I autogenerate C# code using XSD.exe (Visual 2013) I just get this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("response", Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class response {

    private object itemField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TypeA", typeof(TypeAType))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TypeB", typeof(TypeBType))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TypeC", typeof(TypeCType))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("error", typeof(string))]
    public object Item {
        get {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Just a single `Object` field. Not even an enum/value to tell me which element/type it corresponds to, I have to inspect the type or cast. In the past XSD.exe has generated something much more user-friendly. e.g. a field of each type `TypeAType typeAField; string errorField;` etc

My main complaint here is that `error` is just a string. So the only way for me to tell if there is an error is to see if `Item` is a `string`. Which feels really clunky.

Can anyone suggest why XSD.exe is working this way with this XSD and if there is a way to coax it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If the types of the elements in the `choice` differ, xsd.exe generates just a single property of type `object` or of their common base class if they have one. If some of the elements have the same type, xsd.exe generates an additional field and an enum to differentiate between the elements. Here's the documentation on MSDN: [Choice Element Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa6z5baz)

I believe the differentiation by type is more idiomatic, more DRY (an additional enum would just repeat the information that's already in the .NET type system) and easier to use (just set the element's property and not an additional type property, plus `if (x.Item is string) ...` seems easier than `if (x.ItemElementName == ItemChoiceType.TypeA) ...`). But if you really want to have the enum you could introduce an additional dummy element into the `choice` that has the same type as one of the other options.

Comment: Would you mind explaining, provide an example. "Additional dummy element"? This is yet another reason I hate using xsd.exe. The element bindings are simply not as useful now as they used to be in these grey areas. If I have to manually create a enumeration for managed code, it defeats the entire purpose of using it.

Comment: Add another dummy `XmlElementAttribute` that has the same type as one of the other elements, e.g. `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TypeC2", typeof(TypeCType))]`. This forces xsd.exe to generate the additional field and enum.

But as I've said, I'd recommend sticking with the type based approach. C# 7 (VS 2017) makes it even easier to work with the generated code through pattern matching: `if (x.Item is string error) ...`